# Fortran: Counter inside DO-loop

Tags: arrays, fortran, do-loops

I have an array, from which I want to have some information.

I wrote a small DO-loop, but I don't know why it always returns

```
integer :: inn=0
parameter :: m=115200
real*8 :: da1(m)

DO i=1, 115200
    IF( i<=19200 .and. da1(i)>1 .and. da1(i)<999.9999 .and. da1(i)<-1 )then
        inn=inn+1
    END IF
END DO
write(*,*) 'inn=',inn
```

1. why it always prints 0, whereas, I checked in the file and this array indeed has many values in the defined range
2. If the fault is in logic, could someone please give me some pointers on not making such mistakes in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your conditional:

```
da1(i).gt.1.00 .and. da1(i).lt.999.9999 .and. da1(i).lt.-1.000
```

How can a number (here: `da1(i)`) be `> 1` and `< -1` at the same time? That conditional is always false, and `inn` is never incremented.

Comment: I would strongly suggest the OP to use a more readable syntax to see it. I.e., use spaces and symbols `if (  i<19200  .and.  da1(i)>1 .and. da1(i)<999.9999  .and.  da1(i)<-1  ) then`

Comment: @VladimirF Sure, I'll be careful next time. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @PT2009 No need to change the question. It is important to use it in your code to avoid future errors.

Answer (score 2):

Extended comment rather than answer.  The loop could be entirely replaced, probably by

```
count( da1(1:19200)>1 .and. da1(1:19200)<999.999 )
```

I write *probably* because I haven't tested this.

I think looping over a range `i = 1, 115200` and then, inside the loop, testing that `i<=19200` is just wrong.  If you want to loop, write `i = 1, 19200`.